# Big SQL table in html format using python

Tags: python, html, css, sql, beautifulsoup

There is a SQL query that provides output at around 100 lines. What i am trying to do is to replicate that data into html format using python using bs4.BeautifulSoup. So what i get is all data on the html, but i need to scroll down html to see further values of big sql output. What i need is to see full sql output data on html formatt without scrolling down. For example sqLdata is like this:

```
  Col1 Col2 
    1   a
    2   b
    3   b
    4   b
    5   b
    6   b
    7   b
    8   b
    9   b
```

And to see from 5 to 9 i have to scroll my mouse.So i want to have output in html like that:

```
  Col1 Col2    Col1    Col2
    1   a        5       b
    2   b        6       b
    3   b        7       b
    4   b        8       b
                 9       b
```

Python/html code i was using to get that first output:

```
start = '''<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta></head> '''

font_size = '14pt'


style = '''<style media="screen" type="text/css">
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 10%;
  font-size: '''+font_size+''';
}
td {

  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
th {

  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #072FB1;
}
</style>
'''

title = '''<div align="center"></br><font size = "24"><strong>'''+title+'''</strong></font></br></br></</div>'''
```

So thank you in advance for a reply!

Comment: Does not look like a SQL question. which part of code generates your HTML table with results from sql?

Comment: data = df_data.to_html(index = False, na_rep ='')
data = data.replace('None', '')    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)

Comment: Solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802152/html-code-to-show-splitted-data-frame-in-one-html-page-using-python/31806441#31806441