# HTML code to show splitted data_frame in one html page using python

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am newbie in html/css so and having question about data showing in html format. What i have is a long list which i want to split and show in html format as two separate columns.For example instead of:

```
Col1 Col2
1     a
2     a
3     a
4     a
5     b
6     b
7     b
8     b
```

I want to see text as

```
Col1 Col2   Col1   Col2
1     a      5       b
2     a      6       b 
3     a      7       b
4     a      8       b
```

How should my html/css code should look like to have that data above in a splitted table?

For the first output,seeing all data in 2 columns in one table i am using code python:

```
start = '''<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta></head> '''
font_size = '14pt'


style = '''<style media="screen" type="text/css">
table.table1 {

  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 20%;
  font-size: '''+font_size+''';

}

td {

  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
th {

  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #072FB1;
}
</style>
'''

title = '''<div align="center"></br><font size = "24"><strong>'''+title+'''</strong></font></br></br></</div>'''

df_data1 = df_data[1:10]
data = df_data1.to_html( index = False, na_rep ='' )
data = data.replace('None', '')

style_headers = 'background-color: #072FB1; color: #ffffff;'
style_status_new ='background-color: #587EF8; color: #ffffff;font-weight:bold'

style_first_col = 'font-weight:bold;'

total = 'TOTAL'
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data)
soup.thead.tr.attrs['style'] = style_headers

html = start+lentos+style+'''<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">'''+title+time+unicode.join(u'\n',map(unicode,soup))+finish 

try:
    with open(dir_files+'engines_tv_html.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(html.encode('UTF-8'))
except Exception, e:
    log_error()
```

Where in `df_data[1:10]`  i am splitting my data to separate data_frames.
So the question is to see splitted data_frame(one table in the left and another in on the right) in one html page

Comment: Can you show how `df_data` is defined?

Comment: con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=SQL;Database=AA;UID=user;PWD=pswd)
        df_data = pd.io.sql.read_frame(sql_data, con)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is managed by a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), I would suggest you try to build your table using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

```
pd.merge(left=df_data[0:4], left_index=True,
         right=df_data[4:8].reset_index(drop=True), right_index=True,
         suffixes=['_left','_right'], how='outer')

   Col1_left Col2_left  Col1_right Col2_right
0          1         a           5          b
1          2         a           6          b
2          3         a           7          b
3          4         a           8          b
```

Comment: Thank you, but answer does not solve my problem. It is ok, when we do know the exact qty of rows. But for example if we do not know and our data output changes , then this table is not adjusting according to tada qty. For example. if we leave left=df_data[0:4] and right=df_data[4:8] and there will be 7 records, not 8, i will get 3 records in left table and 3 records in a right table. Where i do want to see 4 records in left table and 3 remaining in right table

Comment: @orangutangas The `how='outer'` that I just added will make sure you always get all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution!
When we read data from data_frame, we can firstly trunctate it by desired qty  and then we need to remove previous indexing and then we can concat that data:

```
    pirmas_m = df_data[0:30].reset_index(drop=True)
    antras_m = df_data[30:60].reset_index(drop=True)
    trecias_m = df_data[60:90].reset_index(drop=True)
    ketvirtas_m = df_data[90:120].reset_index(drop=True)
    opa = pd.concat(  [pirmas_m, antras_m, trecias_m, ketvirtas_m], axis=1  )
```